# CORS error in Axios making MondoDB Data API request (serverless)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, axios, cors

I have a Vuejs application from which I want to fetch some data from MongoDB.

I'm using MongoDB API, so I can host the static files on my hosting, serverless.

Using axios I generate the following query:

```
getData() {

      const data = JSON.stringify({
        "collection": "≤MY_COLLECTION>",
        "database": "≤MY_DATABASE>",
        "dataSource": "Cluster0",
        "projection": {
          "_id": 1
        }
      });

      const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-spysy/endpoint/data/beta/action/findOne',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*',
          'api-key': '<MY_API_KEY>',
        },
        data: data
      };

      axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('Error: ',error);
        });
    }
```

When I run it, I get the following error from axios

**Request from another origin blocked: Same-origin policy prevents reading the remote resource at https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/.../findOne (reason: missing CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Status code: 204.**

**Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-spysy/endpoint/data/beta/action/findOne. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null)**

If I make the query with cURL in the same pc it works without problems:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-spysy/endpoint/data/beta/action/findOne' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *' \
--header 'api-key: ≤MY_API_KEY>' \
--data-raw '{
    "collection":"≤MY_COLLECTION>",
    "database":"≤MY_DATABASE>",
    "dataSource":"Cluster0",
    "projection": {"_id": 0}
}'
```